# Razor Dirt Quad kids ATV payload limit

Tags: atv, weight, payload

What is the maximum "payload" (read: the weight the atv can carry besides itself) of the [Razor Dirt Quad kids ATV](http://www.razor.com/products/dirt/dirt-quad/)? The specs say product weight is 89 lbs and something called "Max" is 120 lbs. The question is whether this "Max" is a total limit including product weight or if it is a payload number. In case of total that would leave only some 30 lbs for the kid/payload. While a kid may weight less than 30 lbs I ask myself whether this isn't a bit small number (given the construction of the ATV). But probably isn't, since the electric motor is quite weak... Can anyone confirm?

BTW, the [ATV's manual](http://razor-elektric.cz/image/data/manual/dirtquad_manual_v1_04-11.pdf) states directly on page #1 "DO NOT EXCEED THE WEIGHT LIMIT OF 120 pounds."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a children's toy rather than a real motor vehicle maintenance question.

Comment: Ok, I understand. The reason I asked was because I saw ATV questions are present here.

Comment: It takes several votes to actually close a question.  Comments like the one above are automatically added when you vote to close.  It' s not a big deal.  Your question is worded well and has much more detail than we normally get, so great job there.

Answer (score 3):

The electric, toy quad is made for kids "ages 8+".  The average weight for an 8 year old is 50 lbs, so the 30lb number is obviously not the rider weight limit.

I think it's pretty clear that the rider weight limit is 120 lbs.  It's a toy, so you can't expect nice detailed specifications of "payload capacity" or "towing capacity" or anything else that would be standard for a "vehicle".  I think a number labeled "MAX" is about as much as you could hope for.